# Copy and Paste only if certain cells in columns are blank

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I hope you can help. I have code below. Essentially what it does is, it opens a dialog box that allows a user to select an excel sheet, then it goes out to the country column (11) filters it, then copies and paste that country into a new workbook, names the new workbook after that country then repeats the action for the next country, then it saves and closes each Workbook.

The code works perfectly as is, but what I want it to do now is if there is a cell, or two cells or three cells blank in Columns A, B or C under the header. I want it to only copy and paste these rows for each country.

So in my picture below what I want the code to do is go ah I see that Cell A5 is blank Copy this row and put it into the Belgium workbook, keep going and go ah i see that Cell A14 is blank copy this row and put in the Bulgaria workbook, ah Cell C17 is blank copy this row and put in the Bulgaria workbook. Ah Cell A26, B26 and C26 is blank copy this row and put it in the Croatia workbook.

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my Pic [image]

And here is my code

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your CRO file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)



    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

   With .Range("A1:Y" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Y" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(11).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 11th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 11, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (11th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add '<--... add new Workbook
                        wb.SaveAs Filename:=rCountry.Value2 '<--... saves the workbook after the country
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                               ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                           .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                           Sheets(1).Range("A1:Y1").WrapText = False 'Takes the wrap text off
                           ActiveWindow.Zoom = 55
                         Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit 'Autofits the column
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

It is easy by using xlCellTypeBlanks to copy entire row.
clear all filters and 
replace your **copy code** if you have, otherwise, put it at last

```
dim country as string
row = activesheet.usedrange.rows.count
activesheet.range("A1:C" & row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).entirerow.select
for each r in selection.rows
     country=activesheet.cells(r.row,11)
     r.copy 
     application.workbook(country).sheet(1).rows(1).insert 'assume that your country workbook is already opened
next
```

Comment: Loop shouldn't be necessary if filter by country is done first and you don't need to check for the country name in each row, should just be able to copy and paste as a single set of specialcells

Comment: @Mak: Thank you for the help. I would love to try the code you have provided but where in my existing code would I place this new code?

Comment: @PhilipConnell : I already change the answer, please replace your copy code if you have , otherwise, just put it at last.

Comment: @Mak: Once again thank you so much for your assistance. Its greatly greatly appreciated. My Excel skills are not quiet where they need to be :-) I hope you can help me further. I tried plugging the code you gave here. I removed this line and added your code `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")`But it is not coping the blanks. Have I done something incorrect?